# jenkins hosts unreachable - build failing

Tags: hosts, jenkins, ansible

In my jenkins - build fails in every few days and it shows the below error/message -- 
(this job is running on my jenkins slave machine)

Build o/p -

```
ok=52   changed=5    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

Jenkins Log -

```
May 13, 2020 6:02:36 PM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run

May 11, 2020 12:40:42 PM hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run

May 11, 2020 11:16:11 AM hudson.model.Run execute
```

When I re-trigger the build it completes successfully(Many times have to re-trigger it twice or thrice).

Any suggestions on how to fix it ?

Comment: Have you seen this article from 2017? https://www.automation99.com/2017/09/how-to-setup-jenkins-slave-machine.html

Comment: Yes,Didn't found the resolution thr.